# Image visibility using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to toggle the image using `if-else` but it didn't work, can someone please explain what is wrong with the code.

```
<img src="img/somepic.jpg" id="pic"><br/>

<a href="javascript:toggleImg()">Toggle Image</a>

<script>

function toggleImg(){
    var img = document.getElementById('pic');

    var checkForVisible = img.style.visibility == "visible";

    if(checkForVisible == "visible"){
        img.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else{
        img.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

}

</script>
```

I tried using "ternary operator"

```
img.style.visibility = checkForVisible ? "hidden" : "visible";
```

and it worked. I just want to know about the "if-else" code which doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: `checkForVisible` is a boolean, you're comparing it to `"visible"` again for some reason. Just use `if(checkForVisible)`.

Comment: The answers below are correct, particularly using toggle, but you should try stepping through your code with a debugger and setting a break point on `if(checkForVisible == "visible") {` to see what value the var checkForVisible holds. Learning how to do this will allow you to debug these problems yourself in future.

Answer (score 7):

You do this:

```
var checkForVisible = img.style.visibility == "visible";
```

The == "visible" makes it the result of the equals expression so it's going to be true or false.

Your if/else is checkForVisible == "visible" which won't work because is will only be true or false. You only need to compare once.

```
if(img.style.visibility == "visible"){
        img.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else{
        img.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `toggle` instead of `if else`.

```js
function toggleImg() {
  var img = document.getElementById('pic');
  img.classList.toggle('hidden');

}
```

```css
.visible {
  display: block;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="img/somepic.jpg" id="pic">
<br/>

<a href="javascript:toggleImg()">Toggle Image</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are mistakes. For example in the checkForVisible var. I'n not sure what you're trying to do but there are too many equals.
You can try this out:

```
function toggleImg(){
    var img = document.getElementById('pic');

    img.style.visibility = "visible";

    if(img.style.visibility === "visible"){
        img.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else{
        img.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

}
```