# Display image below original image onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an original image of a person, and then what I want to do is basically click the image, and below a price chart will pop out. so it is hidden until it is clicked, and then if it is clicked again, hide it. I have it set up right now where i can display text, but it isn't really working, and there is no css. here it is:

```html
<img onclick="changeText(1)" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497215728101-856f4ea42174?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60">
<img onclick="changeText(2)" src="def.jpg">
<img onclick="changeText(3)" src="efg.jpg">



<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText(val)
    {

         if(val==1)
         {
              para += "Image one was Clicked";
         }
         else if(val==2)
         {
             para += "Image Two was Clicked";
         }
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image visibility using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36772129/image-visibility-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easies way is to place an element like a `<div>` below the image that contains the price lsit or a etxt instead of an image.

Then hide the element with a class that contains `display: none;` as declaration. Use the onclick event on the image to toggle the class on/off to show/hide the element:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}


/* for stylign purpose only */
img {
  max-width: 30vw;
}
```

```html
<img onclick="document.getElementById('image-label').classList.toggle('hidden')" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497215728101-856f4ea42174?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60">
<div class="hidden" id="image-label">Random Content</div>
```